# How to install Banco do Brasil security solution?

Tags: java, applet

Banco do Brasil uses its own security solution. There's a lack of resources on getting that specific site (Brazilian's largest bank) working on Ubuntu, even in askubuntu.com, so I'm opening this question in order to have a community wiki on the subject.

Comment: ***What is the support question?*** Do you need a Java applet to work, Oracle-Java installed, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

So far, I've found the `oracle-jdk7-installer' from [Webupd8 Team Java PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java) to work. Instructions:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
```